# AngularJS acting weird when changing views - AngularJS & views

Tags: angularjs, load, view, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

My app is acting strange when changing to different views.

The css, javascript code and html parts that were present on the previous view stays on the next view making everything messed up.

mainly problems are with: **ng-show**, **ng-if**, **ng-hide**. they are not evaluating properly. but if a refresh the page, everything goes back to normal.

is it happening because it is loading too fast? why this is happening? how to manage that problem?

Thank you

Comment: In a single page app all css resources are available in all views. Need to show some code if you want help

Comment: correct, it is available to all the application. but it looks like the transitions are happening too fast that the angular cant update it fast enough. i even use ngcloak but it does not make a difference. i cant show code here since i dont know the problem. i will add more info on my question